# Select complement columns between DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas.DataFrame `x`, `x` was fed to function `filter` and returned `y`, a DataFrame with some columns from `x` removed. The function is a blackbox and the column number is large. How could I find the columns in 'x' that are removed?

Or, `y.columns` is a subset of `x.columns`, how could I find the columns in `x` that are not in `y`?

Example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
x.columns = list('abc')
y = x.iloc[:, :2].copy()
>>> x
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
>>> y
   a  b
0  1  2
1  4  5
```

And I'd like to have column `c` returned.

My solution now:

```
>>> xc = x.columns.values.tolist()
>>> yc = y.columns.values.tolist()
>>> diff = [i for i in xc if i not in yc]
>>> x[diff]
   c
0  3
1  6
```

Is there a way to get the result without extracting column names?

I thought this was some sort of basic operations but I couldn't find an easy answer online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) or pandas [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) as:

```
x[x.columns.difference(y.columns)]
```

Or:

```
x[list(set(x.columns)-set(y.columns))]
```

This will give the column values which are in `x` dataframe but not in `y` dataframe.

---

```
print(x[x.columns.difference(y.columns)])
```

or:

```
print(x[list(set(x.columns)-set(y.columns))])

   c
0  3
1  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sets`:

```
x_col = set(x.columns)
y_col = set(y.columns)
x_col.difference(y_col)
>>{'c'}
```

`x_col.difference(y_col)` will return elements that only exist in `x_col` but not in `y_col`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np

diff = np.setdiff1d(xc,yc)
```

OR

But, it's always good to use native methods:

```
diff = list(xc - yc)
```